# Running time in C program on gcc - with and without valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

I have written a program on C and now I am running it on gcc, with valgrind (the program that detects memory loses).

The thing is, when I run it without valgrind, it works **much** faster than with valgrind. I have tried it on several inputs and the result is that when the input is pretty high, is even can not end with valgrind, but without it it takes several seconds.

My program has a lot of calls to malloc in it, Can it be related?

Unfortunately I can not post my code, because it is a part of an assignment, and I have to keep it discrete. This assignment will probably be checked with valgrind, so I have to solve it.

A general answer and possible solutions could help very much.

Thanks

Comment: It's normal. `valgrind` slows down the execution a lot (makes it run several times slower). Why this bothers you?

Comment: [How does Valgrind work](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Science/How-does-Valgrind-work)

Comment: The problem is that my program is automatically checked  with valgrind, and this is how the running tme will be determined - if it is too high I will get a time out and 0 grade.

Comment: @Mike - this sounds ridiculous. The program should be checked for time/performance without `valgrind` and checked with valgrind only for more specific purposes - like cache misses, memory leaks, analyzing what takes more time than the others, etc. It's absurd to measure running time of an application through valgrind. You can't do anything about this.

Comment: I agree, but it is not me who decides that. Every input that is given is checked to see if there are memory leaks, and if it takes too much time.

Comment: @Mike - are you sure these are not two different checks/runs? If they are not, well.. too bad.

Comment: @Mike It would be a very bad idea to perform both checks on the same run with valgrind. Honestly, I don't believe anyone would do that in a CS course. It's totally nonsense. Are you absolutely sure that your program will be timed *while running on valgrind*? And btw, you don't *run* a program on gcc, you *compile* it with gcc.

Comment: Even if there are two different checks, I anyway's can't end the one with valgrind.

Here is an example of a feedback from the program that checks the HW:

(1) 0 line errors, execution time: 0.43 seconds, memory leak: 0 bytes not freed and 0 bytes lost, 33 points out of 33.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely normal. Valgrind emulates your code, keeping trace of allocation, frees, memory access and so on.

From [The Valgrind Quick Start Guide](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html):

```
Your program will run much slower (eg. 20 to 30 times) than normal, and use a lot more memory.
```

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind is among other thing intercepting calls to malloc and free to gather its statistic. This interception is slowing down the call. There is nothing to do against it.